# Сокращение времени билда приложения

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

Билд и запуск приложения в Android Studio 3.0 слишком долгий(иногда 20-25 минут) при развертывании на Android 4.3. При этом при развертывании этого же приложения, на устройствах с 5-6 андроидом билдится всего пару минут. От чего вообще может зависеть скорость билда? И как можно сократить это время, оптимизировать

Comment: Имеете ввиду у вас эмулятор андроид 4.3 и андроид 5. И на пятом  запускается приложение на много быстрее ?

Comment: Нет, не эмулятор, а 2 разных смартфона

Comment: А пробовали запустить на эмуляторе с андроид 4.3 например ? Быстро ?

Comment: Перед тем как начать сильно шаманить, советую попробовать всё на эмуляторе. Делов то. Может дело просто в стареньком смартфоне.

Comment: Я не выдержал андроид студио на ноутбуке с 2-4 минутными установками приложений. Купил i5 плюс SSD, сек 10-30 в зависимости от проекта от начала компиляции до установки, будь то эмулятор , будь то подключенный смартфон. Стоит проверить, чтобы процессор поддерживал технологию аппаратной виртуализации.

Comment: Если зависимости устаканились, включите галку offline mode для gradle. тоже сильно ускорит дело.

Comment: Начиная с Android 5 поддерживается Instant Run - при повторном запуске компилируются только изменённые файлы и накатываются на ранее установленное приложение. Для аппаратов ниже 5 версии производится полная сборка и переустановка приложения. Отсюда такая разница, видимо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

две полезные ссылки на эту тему:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html

https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-decrease-your-gradle-build-time-by-65-310b572b0c43

В частности почитайте как сделать [профилирование билда](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html#profile). Как минимум локализуете проблему.

также может быть Вам поможет [выделение модулей](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) из проекта. Они будут кэшироваться и билдиться параллельно(если в `gradle.properties` пропишите `org.gradle.parallel=true`)

выжимка из второй статьи - измените `gradle.properties` так:

```
#Enable daemon
org.gradle.daemon=true

# Try and findout the best heap size for your project build.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# Modularise your project and enable parallel build
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Enable configure on demand.
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```